# Override open variable for class in Swift and SpriteKit for use in XCode's ActionEditor

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

I'm trying to make small platformer game, just in learning purposes. I've tried to animate character with array of SKTextures like this:

```
let animation: SKAction = SKAction.animate(
    with: frames.map {
        let texture : SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: $0)
        texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest

        return texture
    },
    timePerFrame: 0.15
)
```

`frames` variable is array of SKTextures. I've used `map` to set filtering mode for each texture. This works fine and dandy, but than i've discovered that i can create animations (actions) in ActionEditor in XCode with AnimateWithTextures action. And here lies my problem. This is much more efficient, but i can't change filtering mode for textures in animation ***in ActionEditor***. I've looked into SKTexture class and saw this:

```
open class SKTexture : NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding {
    ...
    /**
    The filtering mode the texture should use when not drawn at native size. Defaults to SKTextureFilteringLinear.
    */
    open var filteringMode: SKTextureFilteringMode
    ...
}
```

If i'm not mistaken `open` means that i can override variable, but i don't know how. I want to set default value of `filteringMode` to `SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest` for all SKTextures so ActionEditor will use textures with texture filtering set to nearest neighbor.

Also if you know how to set filtering mode for textures in specific action – i would like to know how to do it too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can create a function to setup the animation for you, and create an extension to SKTexture with your custom init, and when your ready just call it to your node.

```
extension SKTexture { // Declare this extension outside your class decleration
convenience init(customImageNamed: String) {
    self.init(imageNamed: customImageNamed)
    self.filteringMode = .nearest
}
}

func setupAnimationWithPrefix(_ prefix: String, start: Int, end: Int, timePerFrame: TimeInterval) -> SKAction{
    var textures = [SKTexture]()
    for i in start...end{
        textures.append(SKTexture(customImageNamed: "\(prefix)\(i)"))
    }
    return SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: timePerFrame)
}
```

if you have 10 images named image1, image2, image3 ect..then this is how you would use this function

```
func runAction(){
    let action = setupAnimationWithPrefix("image", start: 1, end: 10, timePerFrame: 0.1) 
    yourNode.run(action)
} // you can change timePerFrame to your liking i find 0.1 sec per frame the best
```

Comment: by the way you should declare the extension outside of the class decleration, and i think setting all of your textures to Nearest filtering mode can be very memory consuming so i would be careful with that

Comment: It's not a problem to set texture filtering for each texture programmatically when i'm creating animation by hand. Reason behind setting default texture filtering to all SKTextures is that i can use ActionEditor.


See my [ActionEditor](http://imgur.com/4pqueNl) and resulted [blurry sprite](http://imgur.com/SmfXBpD)

Comment: oh i get it now the question was a little confusing, anyway i'm not sure if there is a way to do it, personally i try not to use the ActionEditor for this kind of stuff, it's still kind of buggy and has limited options.

Comment: I fixed question a bit. Looks like all i'll have to do that kind of stuff by hand and wait till XCode gets update

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't override a variable without subclassing it, that is to do something like

```
class MyTexture: SKTexture {
```

from there, you could override the variable:

```
  override var filteringMode: SKTextureFilteringMode {
    get {
      return .nearest
    }
    set {
    }
  }
```

That should work, but now you can't change the filtering mode, ever (without going through a bunch of hooplah).

So the more apt way would be to set the default value via the initializer, but `SKTexture` has no public designated initializers, so that option is out of the window.

So your best bet is going to be the `convenience init` extension by Arie, or just make a plain function that returns a new texture:

```
func nearestTexture(imageNamed name: String) -> SKTexture {
   let newTex = SKTexture(imageNamed: name)
   newTex.filteringMode = .nearest
   return newTex
}

let texture: SKTexture = nearestTexture(imageNamed: "lol")
```

Comment: This is a quote from docs about `SKTexture'` : *This class cannot be subclassed.* I haven't tried it yet, nor it is stated why it cannot be subclassed.

Comment: @Whirlwind it compiles when I subclass. maybe there is an rte? Maybe they just meant that you can't set up an initializer (since they are not public)

Comment: @Fludity I guess so, I would have to peek into `SKTexture` class to say more. But private designated inits are certainly an obstacle when it comes to subclassing. Well more precisely, subclassing in that case is not possible :) But as in other answer here, we can use extensions and convenience inits to get around this. I mean, that is probably how I would go, rather than with overriding a filteringMode var.

Comment: @Fludity As i sad in comment for first answer i need to set texture filtering so i can use it in ActionEditor in XCode. If only i could select filtering for Image Set in asset properties

Comment: @kabukiman ok I see what you are saying now. Your code isn't showing you using an action from the editor, so I was confused. I'm leaning pretty heavily towards you not being able to do that :( which sucks because SpriteKit editor has promise but a TON of work left to be really good. Hence why most people I know of stop using it after a few months or so. Cross fingers some love comes this week at WWDC.

Comment: @Fludity I was thinking about `@IBInspectable`. The idea is to create custom field in assets inspector for image and set its `filteringMode` through it. But i don't know how to approach that either.

Comment: @kabukiman it would be more plausible of an idea if SKTexture was subclassable ... but it's not ;( You are probably just going to have to use the editor for designing, then hard code them from that.  You should update your question to reflect what what it is you are really wanting here... on the off chance someone sees it and there is a way. (To include changing the title)

Comment: @Fludity I'm not really sure what type asset editor shows. On the [image](http://i.imgur.com/KvuGdah.png) it says ***Image Set*** and just ***Image***. Maybe there is some wrapper class that i can extend to add custom field. Also i've fixed title and added a little to description, thanks for advice.

Comment: @Whirlwind, you would think they would make SKTexture final if they didn't want it subclassed,  based on the docs I am going to assume they just forgot to add the keyword, and would avoid subclassing since it could become final at any point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

ActionEditor is still very limited in features, you are going to have to write some kind of code behind to allow for texture filtering.  If you do not plan on scaling your sprites (Note I said sprite, not scene, these are two different behaviors), then I would not even worry about texture filtering, the time difference would be negligible.